# Undefined offset: 1 file_get_contents

Tags: php, undefined, file-get-contents, offset

I recently changed my server code does not work anymore while on my old server it works perfectly.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL | E_STRICT);

$myid = "110988448104041785223";
$plus = file_get_contents("http://plus.google.com/$myid/plusones");
$match = array(); 
preg_match('/<div aria-hidden="true" class="BT"><a href="(.*?)"/',$plus,$match);
$data['url'] = $match[1];
echo strtolower($data['url']);
?>
```

**Reurn: Undefined offset: 1 in .... on line 9**

I've added this in .htaccess (I do not know if this is necessary) :

```
php_value magic_quotes 0
php_flag magic_quotes Off
php_value magic_quotes_gpc 0
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
php_flag allow_url_include On
```

PHP Version 5.2.17 - Old server WORK FINE ; and PHP Version 5.3.23 - New server.

Thanks

Comment: `$match[1]` doesn't exist I'd guess. Check your matches before you try to use them

Comment: Can you check this please ? http://codepad.viper-7.com/bNeBUV

Answer (score 0):

That means it's not finding a match, but you are attempting to access the result array regardless.

You should have this:

```
if( preg_match('/<div aria-hidden="true" class="BT"><a href="(.*?)"/',$plus,$match)) {
    $data['url'] = $match[1];
    echo strtolower($data['url']);
}
else echo "ERROR: No match found!";
```

Comment: Thank you but normally he has to find a match...
[link](http://codepad.viper-7.com/bNeBUV)